# Positivity in the proof of the Bezout gcd identity in Apostol's book

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

[Theorem 1.2 of Apostol Analytic Number Theory about common divisor](http://books.google.ie/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=common+divisor+of+a+and+b+has+the+form+d%3Dax%2Bby&source=bl&ots=Jj3UipdIgk&sig=OoEWccFPJ9TqfXkwdAxwmpuDJlw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vxfjT8PDB8iWhQfzrdHVAw&ved=0CE8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=common%20divisor%20of%20a%20and%20b%20has%20the%20form%20d%3Dax%2Bby&f=false) I don't know why but the link needs to be refreshed to see the content

"Theorem 1.2 Each pair of integers a and b has a common divisor d of the form d = ax + by where x and y are integers. Moreover, every common divisor of a and b divides this d. "

His proof seems doesn't depend on y and x can be negative. So if we add a condition that $y \ge x \ge 0$ in the theorem, the proof still works. However, the result will not be true. I am wondering if I miss some points in author's proof?

Also he state this theorem before the greatest common divisor. And it should prove the existence of the GCD since every common divisor divides d. So I think he doesn't assume the GCD exists.

Thanks

Comment: The statement in Apostol seems to be that $\gcd(a,b)$ can be written in the form $ax + by$ for integers $x,y$.  So I would speculate the OP is asking why we cannot further restrict $x,y$ to be *nonnegative* integers, i.e. where in the proof is allowing negative coefficients a critical aspect.

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ The reduction (descent) step of the proof is the same as that of the subtractive form of the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd, i.e. $\rm\ gcd(a,b) = gcd(a-b,b)\ $ for $\rm a\ge b.$ Then by $\rm\color{#c00}{induction}$ we have $\rm\ gcd(a,b) = gcd(a-b,b) \color{#c00}= (a-b) x + b y = a x + b(y-x).\ $ However, the induction step does not lift positivity, i.e. $\rm\ x,y \ge 0 \not\Rightarrow x,\,y\!-\!x \ge 0.\ $

Comment: Hi Bill, Sorry I just read the book so haven't learned Euclidean algorithm. And he doesn't assume the GCD exist in the theorem. Could you give a more direct hint about the proof? And I have edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: @hardmath, Yes that's what I am asking. And the proof seems don't depend on the x,y to be integer. So x, y may be rational number as well?. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Allitee You can safely ignore the remark about the relationship to the Euclidean algorithm - see my answer. Please feel welcome to ask for elaboration in comments if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the inductive step in Apostol's proof you will see that it does not generally lift-up any positivity of the coefficients. Namely, to get a linear common divisor of $\rm\,a,b\,$ it first obtains, by induction, a common divisor $\rm\,d\,$ of $\rm\, a-b,b\,$ of sought linear form $\rm\, d = (a-b)x+by.\,$ Since $\rm\,d\mid a-b,b\,\Rightarrow d\mid (a-b)+b = a,\,$ we infer that $\rm\,d\mid a,b,\,$ i.e. $\rm\,d\,$ is a common divisor of $\rm\,a,b.\,$ Rewriting it yields the desired form: $\rm\,d = (a−b)x+by=ax+b(y−x),\,$ i.e. linear in $\rm\,a,b.$ But this rewriting does not preserve coeff positivity, i.e. from $\rm\,x,y\ge 0\,$ we cannot infer $\rm\,x,y-x\ge 0.\,$

**Remark** $\ $ Readers familiar with the subtractive form of the Euclidean algorithm will note the analogy with the idncution step of the classical proof of the *extended* Euclidean algorithm

$$\rm  gcd(a,b)\overset{\color{#c00}{law}}=gcd(a−b,b)\overset{induct}{=}(a−b)x+by=ax+b(y−x).$$

This gcd $\rm\color{#c00}{law}$ is the reduction (descent) step employed in this algorithm to reduce the given gcd to a "smaller" one, where the size measure used on gcd argument pairs $\rm\,(a,b)\,$ is  their sum $\rm\,a+b.$

Comment: Thank you Bill. But he doesn't state anything about gcd in the proof. Actually, he uses this theorem to introduce the gcd.

Comment: @Allitee I mention the gcd law only to give some intuition on how the proof works. Again you can ignore that if you like. All that matters is my remark that the positivity of the Bezout coefficient does not necessarily lift. You might find it helpful to work out some simple numerical examples to understand how the induction works. You can find some worked examples in some of my prior posts here on the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: In particular, Apostol's proof uses only one direction of said gcd equality, viz. that a common divisor of $\rm\,a-b,\, b\,$ is also a common divisor of $\rm\,a,b.\,$ Essentially he's working with common divisors, instead of *greatest* common divisors, delaying proof of the *greatest* aspect till later.

Comment: So if we just consider his proof, in the basis case of P(1) the induction he says n=a+b=0, d=0 and x=y=0. So the theorem holds for P(1). And subsequently he assumes the theorem holds for each j=a+b between [0,n-1] and induces P(n). But if we add a further restriction "y≥x≥0" in the theorem to prove, the proof seems still work since the basis case is also true and the induction step doesn't depend on the sign of x,y.

Comment: @Allitee Apostol is using a slightly different proof than I imagined. I just now rewrote my answer so it is clearer how it applies to his proof. The (complete) induction is on the sum $\rm\,n\,$ of the arguments of the gcd function. Induction lifts the proof for the "smaller" argument pair $\rm\,(a-b,b)\,$ of size $\rm\,n = (a-b)+b = a\,$ to the larger argument pair $\rm\,(a,b)\,$ of size $\rm\,n = a+b.\,$

Comment: If we add the restriction "y≥x≥0" then we can infer infer x,y−x≥0 in the induction step. So can we prove "Each pair of integers a and b has a common divisor d of the form d = ax + by where $\rm\color{#c00}{y≥x≥0}$ . Moreover, every common divisor of a and b divides this d. "  using the same proof?

Comment: @Allitee Not necessarily. Notice the step "by symmetry we may assume $\, a\ge b.\,$" This works by swapping the arguments if need be, so that the first is the greatest. If it swaps the arguments then one must also swap coefficients $\,x,y,\,$ which will not preserve the inequality $\,y \ge x.$

Comment: I see. But if we add a≥b, can we prove the above statement using his proof? If we can, for a=3,b=2, we can't get the common divisor d = 3x + 2y for y≥x≥0, which should be 1?

Comment: Generally you cannot infer any inequalities on the coefficients because of the possible swapping that may occur. By definition of divisibility, $\, 0\mid n\iff n = 0,\,$ so  $\,0\,$ is a common divisor of $\,a,b\,$ iff both are $\,0.\ $

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what the possible swapping means. If we fix y be the coefficient on b and x be the coefficient on a. Add a ≥ b,  y≥x≥0 to the statement. Since the basis case is true and the induction step infers the final n case. Should the original proof be applicable as well?

Comment: @Allitee I'm not sure precisely what you're saying. If you run the proof/algorithm on a few small examples then this should quickly yield the insight needed to conclude the analysis. Alternatively, write your envisioned proof in full detail in your question so that we can see *precisely* what you intend.